# What is the group of isometries of the plane preserving this frieze?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, cyclic-groups, group-isomorphism, group-homomorphism

Consider the following frieze:

[image: frieze]

How would you find the group isometries of the plane preserving this frieze?

I'm not really sure how to do this, but I assume that it would help to start by ladling the triangles and adding coordinates, as follows:

[image: Labeled frieze]

Here, to get from triangle A to triangle B, a rotation $R_{n}$ of $\pi$ rads about the point $(1,0)$ would be required, so I suppose this would be one isomorphism.

Furthermore, getting from triangle A to triangle C would require a translation $T_{n}$ of 2 units in the $x$ direction, which could be expressed as $T_{n}(x,y)=(x+2, y)$.

How would you express the rotation in the form $R_{n}(x,y)=(f(x), f(y))$?

Are there any other isometries that I've missed?

Comment: For starters, can you name some isometries preserving this frieze?   (Also, how are you expected to specify the answer - do you already know the list of all possible isometry groups for friezes, and just need to pick one from the list?)

Comment: To be honest, I'm scarcely even sure what a frieze is, so how one should find the isometries of one is something I don't know how to go about doing. I'm guessing that there would be translational and rotational ones though, but how am I to know if there are others that I've not thought of?

Comment: You should read this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frieze_group particularly the section labeled "Description of the seven frieze groups"

Comment: The two points you've labelled (0,1) and (1,0) - those are not the same distance from (0,0) in your picture...

Comment: *diagram not drawn to scale*